# How to implement nested loops in cuda thrust

Tags: loops, cuda, thrust

I currently have to run a nested loop as follow:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j <= N; j++){
        compute(...)//some calculation here
    }
}
```

I've tried leaving the first loop in `CPU` and do the second loop in `GPU`. Results are `too many memory access`. Is there any other ways to do it? For example by `thrust::reduce_by_key`?

The whole program is here:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/binary_search.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#define N 1000000

// define a 2d point pair
typedef thrust::tuple<float, float> Point;

// return a random Point in [0,1)^2
Point make_point(void)
{
  static thrust::default_random_engine rng(12345);
  static thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(0.0f, 1.0f);
  float x = dist(rng);
  float y = dist(rng);
  return Point(x,y);
}

struct sqrt_dis: public thrust::unary_function<Point, double>
{
  float x, y;
  double tmp;
  sqrt_dis(float _x, float _y): x(_x), y(_y){}
  __host__ __device__
  float operator()(Point a)
 {
    tmp =(thrust::get<0>(a)-x)*(thrust::get<0>(a)-x)+\
    (thrust::get<1>(a)-y)*(thrust::get<1>(a)-y);
    tmp = -1.0*(sqrt(tmp));
    return (1.0/tmp);
 }

};


int main(void) {
  clock_t t1, t2;
  double result;

  t1 = clock();
  // allocate some random points in the unit square on the host
  thrust::host_vector<Point> h_points(N);
  thrust::generate(h_points.begin(), h_points.end(), make_point);

  // transfer to device
  thrust::device_vector<Point> points = h_points;

  thrust::plus<double> binary_op;
  float init = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    Point tmp_i = points[i];
    float x = thrust::get<0>(tmp_i);
    float y = thrust::get<1>(tmp_i);
    result += thrust::transform_reduce(points.begin()+i,\
                                       points.end(),sqrt_dis(x,y),\
                                       init,binary_op);
    std::cout<<"result"<<i<<": "<<result<<std::endl;
  }
  t2 = clock()-t1;
  std::cout<<"result: ";
  std::cout.precision(10);
  std::cout<< result <<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"run time: "<<t2/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"s"<<std::endl;
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: do you need the overall sum in `result` or do you need the per loop iteration sum?

Comment: overall sum in result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Now that you have posted an example, here is how you could solve it:

You have `n` 2D points stored in a linear array like this (here `n=4`)

```
points = [p0 p1 p2 p3]
```

Based on your code I assume you want to calculate:

```
result = f(p0, p1) + f(p0, p2) + f(p0, p3) +
         f(p1, p2) + f(p1, p3) +
         f(p2, p3)
```

Where `f()` is your distance function which needs to be executed `m` [times in total](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%28n-k%29):

```
m = (n-1)*n/2
```

in this example: `m=6`

You can look at this problem as a triangular matrix:

```
[ p0 p1 p2 p3 ] 
[    p1 p2 p3 ]
[       p2 p3 ]
[          p3 ]
```

Transforming this matrix into a linear vector with `m` elements while leaving out the diagonal elements results in:

```
[p1 p2 p3 p2 p3 p3]
```

The index of an element in the vector is `k = [0,m-1]`.
Index `k` can be [remapped to columns and rows of the triangular matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27088560/678093) to `k -> (i,j)`:

```
i = n - 2 - floor(sqrt(-8*k + 4*n*(n-1)-7)/2.0 - 0.5)
j = k + i + 1 - n*(n-1)/2 + (n-i)*((n-i)-1)/2
```

`i` is the row and `j` is the column.

In our example:

```
0 -> (0, 1)
1 -> (0, 2)
2 -> (0, 3)
3 -> (1, 2)
4 -> (1, 3)
5 -> (2, 3)
```

Now you can put all this together and execute a modified distance functor `m` times which applies the aforementioned mapping to get the corresponding pairs based on the index and then sum up everything.

I modified your code accordingly:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define PRINT_DEBUG

typedef float Float;

// define a 2d point pair
typedef thrust::tuple<Float, Float> Point;

// return a random Point in [0,1)^2
Point make_point(void)
{
    static thrust::default_random_engine rng(12345);
    static thrust::uniform_real_distribution<Float> dist(0.0, 1.0);
    Float x = dist(rng);
    Float y = dist(rng);
    return Point(x,y);
}


struct sqrt_dis_new
{
    typedef thrust::device_ptr<Point> DevPtr;

    DevPtr points;
    const uint64_t n;

    __host__
    sqrt_dis_new(uint64_t n, DevPtr p) : n(n), points(p)
    {
    }

    __device__ 
    Float operator()(uint64_t k) const
    {
        // calculate indices in triangular matrix
        const uint64_t i = n - 2 - floor(sqrt((double)(-8*k + 4*n*(n-1)-7))/2.0 - 0.5);
        const uint64_t j = k + i + 1 - n*(n-1)/2 + (n-i)*((n-i)-1)/2;

#ifdef PRINT_DEBUG
        printf("%llu -> (%llu, %llu)\n", k,i,j);
#endif

        const Point& p1 = *(points.get()+j);
        const Point& p2 = *(points.get()+i);

        const Float xm = thrust::get<0>(p1)-thrust::get<0>(p2);
        const Float ym = thrust::get<1>(p1)-thrust::get<1>(p2);

        return 1.0/(-1.0 * sqrt(xm*xm + ym*ym));
    }
};


int main()
{
    const uint64_t N = 4;

    // allocate some random points in the unit square on the host
    thrust::host_vector<Point> h_points(N);
    thrust::generate(h_points.begin(), h_points.end(), make_point);

    // transfer to device
    thrust::device_vector<Point> d_points = h_points;

    const uint64_t count = (N-1)*N/2;

    std::cout << count << std::endl;


    thrust::plus<Float> binary_op;
    const Float init = 0.0;

    Float result = thrust::transform_reduce(thrust::make_counting_iterator((uint64_t)0),
                                            thrust::make_counting_iterator(count),
                                            sqrt_dis_new(N, d_points.data()),
                                            init,
                                            binary_op);

    std::cout.precision(10);  
    std::cout<<"result: " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

It depends on your `compute` function which you do not specify.
Usually you unroll the loops and launch the kernel in a 2D manner for every combination of `i` and `j` if the computations are independent.
Have a look at the Thrust examples and identify similar use cases to your problem.

Comment: I've posted my current version.